# C# datasource gives System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datasource

I have tried to use Datasource in C# and got:

```
System.NullReferenceException
```

my code is:

```
public class Registration:Init
{
    private TestContext testContextInstance;

    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get
        {
            return testContextInstance;
        }
        set
        {
            testContextInstance = value;
        }
    }
    [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", "|DataDirectory|\\DataSource\\RegistrationTestData.csv", "RegistrationTestData#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), DeploymentItem("DataSource\\RegistrationTestData.csv")]
    public String Register(String sClientlabel,UserRegistrationDetails uUserdetailes,StepResult sResults)

    {

        String sActivation = null;
        string sPassword = this.TestContext.DataRow["Password"].ToString();
        String susername = TestContext.DataRow["BrainLab ID"].ToString();}
```

Does anybody have an idea why sPassword is null?

Comment: You're saying sPassword is null, what's this.TestContext.DataRow["Password"]?

Comment: where did you set your `TestContext` ?? and when did you call Register method?

Comment: Post the Actual Error message that is displayed to you

Comment: On what line do you get the exception? You need to explain more fully, because `sPassword` is *not* the null reference (more likely `this.TestContext` or `this.TestContext.DataRow["Password"]` is).

Answer (score 0):

Your method does not have the `[TestMethod()]` attribute on it, which makes me wonder how it's  getting called.  If you are calling this method from each test, I'm not sure your method will work since the test framework is probably looking for the `DataSource` attribute *on the test method itself*.  You may need to move the `[DataSource]` attribute to each test, or load the metadata directly in the `Register` method.

Comment: Thanks how do I load the metadata directly in the Register method?

Comment: I call this class method from my test

Comment: @Amir `[DataSource]` is designed to use external data _for each test_.  It is not designed to automatically load common data for _all_ tests.  You _could_ add the `[DataSource]` attribute to each test case, or you could use a different process to read the CSV file in your test setup (config file?).  I don't know of a way to use `[DataSource]` to load common configuration data.

Answer (score 0):

Empty fields in the data source are read as `null` strings so a statement such as

```
string sPassword = this.TestContext.DataRow["Password"].ToString();
```

is evaluated as:

```
string sPassword = null.ToString();
```

Empty fields can be because of fields containing only white space, also from blank lines within the data source file. Note that a CSV file may finish with one CRLF pair without that being regarded as a blank line. If the file finishes with two or more CRLF pairs then the file finishes with blank lines that will provoke the reported error.